# pandas groupby and agg operation of selected columns and row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below:

[image]

I am not sure if it is possible to use pandas to make an output as below:

difference=Response[df.Time=="pre"]-Response.min for each group

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pre` is always first per groups and values in output should be repeated:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('IDs')['Response'].transform(lambda x: (x.iat[0] - x).min())
```

For only first value per groups is possible replace values to empty strings, but get mixed values - numeric with strings, so next processing should be problem:

```
df['diff'] = df['diff'].mask(df['diff'].duplicated(), '')
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Response':[2,5,0.4,2,1,4],
         'Time':[7,'pre',9,4,2,'pre'],
         'IDs':list('aaabbb')
})
#print (df)

d = df[df.Time=="pre"].set_index('IDs')['Response'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'a': 5.0, 'b': 4.0}

df['diff'] = df.groupby('IDs')['Response'].transform(lambda x: d[x.name] - x.min())
print (df)
   Response Time IDs  diff
0       2.0    7   a   4.6
1       5.0  pre   a   4.6
2       0.4    9   a   4.6
3       2.0    4   b   3.0
4       1.0    2   b   3.0
5       4.0  pre   b   3.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much. What if the "pre" is not always as the first row per group, do we have a way to process it ?(The solution I can think about is to sort "Time" column first before transforming.

Comment: @derec - There is alwasy only one `pre` value per group?

Comment: Smart. Solution is well noted. Thanks.